# Is there a more efficient way to calculate monthly portfolio values from customer portfolios?

Tags: r, dataframe, portfolio

The following two data frames are a snippet from the data I am currently working with. df1 contains the history of investors (separated by id) with the amount of shares from different products they own. Every time there is a change in the amount of shares, a new entry is created. df2 contains the prices corresponding to the products.

I am trying to calculate monthly portfolio values for all the customers during their investment period.
Here a reproducible example of df1 and df2:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(timeDate)

#create df1 customer portfolio history 
id <- c("1","1","1","1","2","2","2","3","3","3","3","3")
df1 <- data.frame(id)
df1$start <- as.Date(c("2012-03-11", "2012-04-17","2012-05-09", "2012-05-11", "2012-11-17","2012-12-09",
"2013-01-21", "2011-06-27","2012-07-02", "2012-07-21", "2012-09-03","2012-09-16"))
df1$end <- as.Date(c("2012-05-08", "2012-05-21","2012-06-11", "2012-11-16", "2012-12-08","2013-01-20",
"2013-02-03", "2011-07-01","2012-09-15", "2012-09-02", "2012-09-20","2012-09-16"))
df1$product <- c("a","b","a","b","b","b","b","c","c","a","a","c")
df1$amount <- as.numeric(c("5","12","7","11","3","8","6","4","1","16","17","9"))

#create df2 with corresponding Prices 
date <- seq.Date(from = as.Date("2011-05-01"), to = as.Date("2013-02-01"), by = "month")
df2 <- data.frame(date)
df2$product <- "a"
date <- seq.Date(from = as.Date("2012-04-01"), to = as.Date("2013-02-01"), by = "month")
date <- data.frame(date)
date$product <- "b"
df2 <- rbind(df2,date)
date <- seq.Date(from = as.Date("2011-06-01"), to = as.Date("2012-09-01"), by = "month")
date <- data.frame(date)
date$product <- "c"
df2 <- rbind(df2,date)
df2$price <- as.numeric(sample(100, size = nrow(df2), replace = TRUE))
df2$date <- as.Date(timeLastDayInMonth(df2$date))
```

What i ended up doing was to spread my investor data into a wide format and artificially add a row with the date at the end of every month. Then I proceeded to do the same with my price data, join both tohether and ultimately calculate the portfolio values with rowSums.

Here is my code for the data frames above:

```
#convert to wide data
df1 <- df1 %>%
spread(product, amount, fill = NA, convert = FALSE) 
colnames(df1)[4:6] <- paste("xxx", colnames(df1[,c(4:6)]), sep = "_")    

#add end of month observations to data frame
seq <- df1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(start= floor_date(AddMonths(min(start),-1), "month"),end=max(end)) %>%
  group_by(rn=row_number()) %>%
  do(data.frame(id=.$id, datum=seq(.$start,.$end,by="1 month"))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-rn)

seq <- seq %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(start = as.Date(timeLastDayInMonth(datum))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-2)

df1 <- full_join(df1,seq, by = c("id","start"))
df1 <- df1[with(df1, order(id, start)),]

#create grouping variable and filter all end of month data
df1<- df1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(grp = as.numeric(as.Date(start)- as.Date(timeLastDayInMonth(start))))

df1 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  fill(4:6, .direction = "down")

df1 <- filter(df1, grp == 0)

na_sub <- function(x) { x[is.na(x)] <- 0; x }
df1 <- df1 %>%
  select(-end, -grp) %>%
  na_sub()

#Join both wide dataframes and calculate monthly portfoliovalues
df2 <- df2 %>%
  spread(product, price, fill = NA, convert = FALSE) 
colnames(df2)[2:4] <- paste("yyy", colnames(df2[,c(2:4)]), sep = "_")
names(df2)[names(df2) == "date"] <- "start"

df1 <- left_join(df1, df2, by = "start") 

df1$portfoliovalue <- rowSums(select(df1, starts_with("xxx_")) * select(df1, starts_with("yyy_")), na.rm = TRUE)
```

The code leads to the desired result with the monthly portfolio values for every investor. As I mentioned, this is a snippet of the whole data. Unfortunately i run into trouble especially with the size of the wide data frames (as they get a massive amount of columns due to the increasing number of products). This makes it impossible to run the code with a larger data set. Is it possible to keep the data in a long format for the calculations? Are there packages which offer procedures for such calculations?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some functions in package [`PMwR`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=PMwR) can help. (Disclosure: I am the package maintainer.) With [`PMwR`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=PMwR), you can create journals (i.e. flows, changes in positions) and then compute positions. For instance:

```
library("PMwR")
library("datetimeutils")
j <- journal(account    = rep(df1$id, 2),
             instrument = rep(df1$product, 2),
             amount     = c(df1$amount, -df1$amount),
             timestamp  = c(df1$start, df1$end))

month.ends <- nth_day(start = as.Date("2012-01-01"),
                      end   = as.Date("2012-12-31"),
                      n = "last", period = "month")

position(j, when = month.ends, use.account = TRUE)
##            1:a 1:b 2:b 3:a 3:c
## 2012-01-31   0   0   0   0   0
## 2012-02-29   0   0   0   0   0
## 2012-03-31   5   0   0   0   0
## 2012-04-30   5  12   0   0   0
## 2012-05-31   7  11   0   0   0
## 2012-06-30   0  11   0   0   0
## 2012-07-31   0  11   0  16   1
## 2012-08-31   0  11   0  16   1
## 2012-09-30   0  11   0   0   0
## 2012-10-31   0  11   0   0   0
## 2012-11-30   0   0   3   0   0
## 2012-12-31   0   0   3   0   0
```

More details are in the [manual](http://enricoschumann.net/R/packages/PMwR/manual/PMwR.html).

*Update* When you call `position` with the `when` argument, you
get one position for each value in `when`. A simple way
to add an `id` is to loop over the ids, transform the
position for every `id` into data frame and then merge these data
frames. (One cannot directly call `rbind`, since the
products may differ per `id`.)

```
accounts <- unique(j$account)
for (a in accounts)
    if (a == accounts[1]) {
        result <- data.frame(timestamp = month.ends,
                             id = a,
                             position(j[j$account == a],
                                      when = month.ends))
    } else {
        result <- merge(result,
                        data.frame(timestamp = month.ends,
                                   id = a,
                                   position(j[j$account == a],
                                            when = month.ends)),
                        all = TRUE)
    }

result[is.na(result)] <- 0
result
##     timestamp id  a  b c
## 1  2012-01-31  1  0  0 0
## 2  2012-01-31  2  0  0 0
## 3  2012-01-31  3  0  0 0
## 4  2012-02-29  1  0  0 0
## 5  2012-02-29  2  0  0 0
## 6  2012-02-29  3  0  0 0
## 7  2012-03-31  1  5  0 0
## 8  2012-03-31  2  0  0 0
## 9  2012-03-31  3  0  0 0
## 10 2012-04-30  1  5 12 0
## 11 2012-04-30  2  0  0 0
## 12 2012-04-30  3  0  0 0
## 13 2012-05-31  1  7 11 0
## 14 2012-05-31  2  0  0 0
## 15 2012-05-31  3  0  0 0
## 16 2012-06-30  1  0 11 0
## 17 2012-06-30  2  0  0 0
## 18 2012-06-30  3  0  0 0
## 19 2012-07-31  1  0 11 0
## 20 2012-07-31  2  0  0 0
## 21 2012-07-31  3 16  0 1
## 22 2012-08-31  1  0 11 0
## 23 2012-08-31  2  0  0 0
## 24 2012-08-31  3 16  0 1
## 25 2012-09-30  1  0 11 0
## 26 2012-09-30  2  0  0 0
## 27 2012-09-30  3  0  0 0
## 28 2012-10-31  1  0 11 0
## 29 2012-10-31  2  0  0 0
## 30 2012-10-31  3  0  0 0
## 31 2012-11-30  1  0  0 0
## 32 2012-11-30  2  0  3 0
## 33 2012-11-30  3  0  0 0
## 34 2012-12-31  1  0  0 0
## 35 2012-12-31  2  0  8 0
## 36 2012-12-31  3  0  0 0
```

Comment: This is indeed an excellent package to work with. Congratulations on your work! I have a question though about the output. In your output the `id` is added to the columns with the command `position(j, when = month.ends, use.account = TRUE)`. Would it be possible to have a separate column with the `id` next to the timestamps instead of replicating the columns with the products? Otherwise this is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Thank you. I have expanded  my answer.